# Large MongoDB Import - Exceeding 4096 character limit

Tags: json, mongodb

I have a large JSON file (around 20,000 lines) which I need to import to mongoDB. I've imported a similar dataset before but that did not break mongo's 4096 character limit in the shell.

I've tried running:

`db.machines.insert([DATA HERE]);` - but this breaks the character limit

I've also tried running:

`mongoimport --collection machines --file data.json`

However this only imports ONE document.

I've also tried saving `db.machines.insert([DATA HERE]);` into a JS file and running `mongo insert.js`

However the documents have not appeared in the collection

Here is some sample data, there about 1000 documents that need adding to the collection:

```
servers: {
 "host2":   {
"hostname": "1",
"description": "",
"cluster": "1",
"type": "Virtual",
"os": "RHEL 6.3",
"idc": "PKY",
"environment": "PROD",
"deviceclass": "server",
"cores": "8",
"memory": "16",
"roles": ["ATG-WEB"] 
 },
 "host1":   {
"hostname": "1",
"description": "",
"cluster": "1",
"type": "Virtual",
"os": "RHEL 6.3",
"idc": "PKY",
"environment": "PROD",
"deviceclass": "server",
"cores": "8",
"memory": "16",
"roles": ["ATG-WEB"],
}
}
```

I'm running out of ideas!

Comment: use another language, and insert each value individually, 1-at-a-time?

Comment: That seems like an awfully long way of doing this given I'm running on a linux box without LAMP or similar installed.

Comment: Alternatively, use MongoDB's `mongoimport` tool (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/)

Comment: @mnemosyn - I've tried using mongoimport but it just adds one document to the collection - not the 1000+ I'm expecting

Comment: Please post some sample data that shows the *outer* structure of the data. The inner structure isn't too relevant here.

Comment: That is because your JSON only has one object which is "servers", and keys underneath it for each "host". Any attempt at importing/inserting this is going to be interpreted as one document. You can instead split the content into an array instead of keyed documents, or better yet for `mongoimport` split each host to a single line. Then in will import as separate documents.

Comment: @mnemosyn I think the problem here given the "imported one document" is that this "is" the outer structure and each "host" is expected to be a separate document. At least that's my reading of it.

Comment: Yep, I simply couldn't believe someone would actually try to use a named document, because that is invalid JSON and shouldn't be accepted by `mongoimport` at all. Unfortunately, `mongoimport` is pretty lax...

Comment: @BlakesSeven - Which is the best way to split them? Are there any parsers online that will do this?

Comment: @BlakesSeven is correct - servers is the outer structure and the hosts are the inner structure

Comment: Do you have no control of the source of this? Fixing it there would be ideal. If not then there might be a stream parser available for node or other language that would split up the document. I don't think the mongodb shell would be too happy about loading this and then cycling the Object keys. And then there is always `sed`. It just depends on your constraints

Comment: Unfortunately I am stuck with this format

Comment: So what are your constraints? Are you just stuck with mongodb and unix tools? Or can you deploy another program to handle this? Especially if the former, then is this actually multi-line? Or is it all really just spat out on a single line in the file?

Comment: I'd like to use mongodb and unix tools. I think I will use sed..

Comment: Have fun then. `sed` is line based, so while possible it takes some mucking around. I would also advise "retooling" your question to actually be "manipulate a json file" showing what you need as a result. Throwing it at `bash|sed|awk` tags will also make the goal clear.

Comment: Thanks - I got it working in the end :)

Comment: Please post what you did as an aswer then. Others with a similar data structure might find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I have used mongoImport without problems for large data (fews Gb).
Your JSON structure looks incorrect.
Please validating your JSON first: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

After, you have 2 solutions:

**Solution 1:**

Change your JSON structure to be an array of objects.
Your JSON structure is not an array of object (which will be representing by a Document). 
You should do something like that:

```
[{    
"hostname": "1",
"description": "",
"cluster": "1",
"type": "Virtual",
"os": "RHEL 6.3",
"idc": "PKY",
"environment": "PROD",
"deviceclass": "server",
"cores": "8",
"memory": "16",
"roles": ["ATG-WEB"] 
 },
{
"hostname": "2",
"description": "",
"cluster": "1",
"type": "Virtual",
"os": "RHEL 6.3",
"idc": "PKY",
"environment": "PROD",
"deviceclass": "server",
"cores": "8",
"memory": "16",
"roles": ["ATG-WEB"]
}]
```

**Solution 2:**

If you can, Try using MongoImport with CSV format, it's working good too. One line by document to insert.